# HorizontalPanel in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have added a `Label` and a `ListBox` in a `HorizontalPanel` as a header of a web page. When I set the left margin of a label and the right margin of a listbox and change the size of the window, their positions change. It would be great if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

```java
    HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
    Label label = new Label("Test Program");
    label.addStyleName("test-label");

    ListBox listbox = new ListBox();
    listbox.addItem("test1");
    listbox.addItem("test2");       
    listbox.addStyleName("test-listbox");

    hp.add(title);        
    hp.add(language);
```

CSS file:

```css
   .test-label{float:left}
   .test-listbox{float:right}
```

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have heard if I use percentage instead of pixel in margin and change the size of the window or use different browsers the positions of widgets change based on the size of window. I have used percentage but when I change the size of window the label and the listbox are vanished.

Comment: Instead of CSS, try hp.setCellHorizontalAlignment(title, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT); and hp.setCellHorizontalAlignment(language, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);

Comment: thanks but if I want to set the margin for these two widgets in a horizontal panel what I can do? I want them to have flexible position with the window size.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you code setting the `HorizontalPanel` to a 100% `width`. I tried adding margins to the elements and they work fine. Please note i suspect your vanish behaviour might be due to rogue additions

```java
**hp.add(title);**        
**hp.add(language);**
```

Your declarations have `label` and `listbox` and you are adding `title` and `language`.

Sample Code :

```java
    HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
    hp.addStyleName("testWidth");
    Label label = new Label("Test Program");
    label.addStyleName("test-label");

    ListBox listbox = new ListBox();
    listbox.addItem("test1");
    listbox.addItem("test2");
    listbox.addStyleName("test-listbox");

    hp.add(label);
    hp.add(listbox);

    RootPanel.get().add(hp);
```

CSS

```css
.test-label {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.test-listbox {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.testWidth{
    width: 100%;
}
```